# Where is "setTimeout" from JavaScript in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

Is there an implementation of `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` in Haxe?
It's of course possible to use the `Timer` class, but for a one-shot execution it's not the best way, I guess.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a one-shot execution I think that [`Timer.delay()`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/Timer.html#delay) is perfect. You can use the returned instance to stop the timer later:

```
var timer = haxe.Timer.delay(function() trace("Hello World!"), 250);
...
timer.stop();
```

You could also access the native `setTimeout()` with the [`js.html.Window`](https://api.haxe.org/js/html/Window.html) extern:

```
var handle = js.Browser.window.setTimeout(function() trace("Hello World!"), 250);
...
js.Browser.window.clearTimeout(handle);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using the [kha](/questions/tagged/kha) framework:

Kha modifies `haxe.Timer` to call `kha.Scheduler`, which in the end doesn't get the `timestamps` via `setTimeout` - it gets these via `requestAnimationFrame()`.

This seems to not work while a tab is inactive, so it's not the same function while the tab is inactive.

I'm attempting a workaround, but at the moment, it doesn't give the same result as a native `setTimeout()`-JS does (although I found a workaround which I'll present for inclusion).